# Using laravel mix to include js dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

i can't really get my js libraries  to work , some time ago i decided to have a separate js file for every library i use (so i have a jquery.js file and a bootstrap.js file included in my layout) ,everything was working just fine until i had to add jquery-ui to  this chaos , and got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function
```

until i loaded ,jquery and jquery-ui in the same file .The problem is i dont want to include jquery ui everywhere i include jquery , beacuse i only use it in 2 pages. Below i will put my code :

**jquery-ui.slider.js:**

```
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/slider');
require('./components/carFilter.js');
```

**app.js:**

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('./bootstrap');
```

**webpack.mix.js:**

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
mix.js('resources/assets/js/jquery-ui.slider.js', 'public/js');
```

I am using the following npm modules :

- bootstrap-sass
- jquery
- jquery-ui

Comment: If you still curious to digging up such question, here's a referece https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/

Comment: thank you @Chay22  , i will study it later , if i find a beter way , i will post it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up by just creating a file where i require jquery,bootstrap.js and then i require this file in a specific file for the two pages...
Below its the code:

**app.js**

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('./bootstrap');
```

**page.js**

```
require('./app.js')
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/slider');
```

It seams that now it is working ,even if now i have to include a js file in all the views...Question its still open , i hope somone have a beter idea .

Answer (score 2):

I think `laravel-mix` only serves the purpose when you have small sites with pages that all include the same `app.js` & `app.css` files.

When you have complex portal with multiple pages that have different set of frontend "plugins" you have to split your entries & generate a table of dependencies automatically.

After a lot of time searching I've come to the conclusion that the best approach would be switch to `webpack-encore` from Symfony.

You can read more about it's capabilities here [Webpack Encore Official Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html).

Now the question is how to embed it to Laravel? It's quite easy, I've just reverse engineered the Symfony's PHP bundle for that and here is the result:
https://github.com/ntpages/laravel-encore

Now you just have to include you're dependency in the page entry and it's all handled automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should load jquery-ui when a condition is met, like:

```
if (window.loadJQueryUI) {
    require('jquery-ui');
}
```

And you need to initialize `loadJQueryUI` for the two pages, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.loadJQueryUI = true;
</script>
```